# How to give HTTP API or REST API with Lambda, the ability to not update?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

So I have a Lambda Function with the code below, which is triggered by an API (AWS API Gateway).

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    testString = "foo"
    if "f" in testString:
        return {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "body": json.dumps(testString)
        }
```

I tested it with both a HTTP API and a REST API. Because the condition returns `True`, in both cases the output is `"foo"` as it should be. But what happens if `testString` suddenly changes to `"goo"`, and the condition returns `False`? I would like the output to remain as it previously was (not update), so it remains `"foo"`. But when this happens, the HTTP API outputs `null`, and the REST API outputs `{"message": "Internal server error"}`.

Maybe I just need to figure out the missing piece in the code below:

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    testString = "goo"
    if "f" in testString:
        return {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "body": json.dumps(testString)
        }
    else:
        #missing piece: make output not change
```

This is probably the first time, I have tried "creating" APIs tbh. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like the output t remain as it previously was (not update), so it remains "foo"

You can't do this with just only a lambda function. You have to **store your previous outputs externally**, e.g. in a `DynamoDB`. Then your function will always be able to look up the last correct result and return it instead some random error message or incorrect answer.

Comment: If that is the only way, than how would you suggest I do it?

Comment: It is a single string so DynamoDB doesn't make sense, the lambda function should be able to update it, so environment variable is not an option.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman I already told you how. You need to setup DynamoDB, and program your lambda function to store the results and query it for last results. You can use other store if you don't want dynamodb. SSM Paramtere Store for example.

Comment: "foo" and "goo" are just examples here but the real string can have more than 80,000 characters, which is why I can't use SSM Parameter Store, because the limit is 4kb or 8kb.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman So use whatever you want, RDS, S3. The point is that lambda does not store data permanently. Your output must be sorted outside of lambda.

Comment: Yeah I got that. Just asking how would u store a single string, more than 80,000 character long, that optionally needs to update?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman I would suggest trying to develop such a solution, and if you get stuck, please make new question specific to that new issue.

Comment: Right, but is there like a non Lambda way to do this maybe, that does have ability to not update output?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman I'm not sure what do you mean by "update output". Its better to make new question with actual examples of what are these outputs, how to updated them, when, etc.

Comment: I simply mean the output does not change. In this case it remains "foo". But I get your point. Thanks.